# How can I use pipeline in System.cmd?

Tags: cmd, elixir

I have a function, which gets information of all usb connected devices.

`connected_devices = :os.cmd('usb-devices | grep -A 1 Product=')`

When I use `:os.cmd`, it works fine. However, since `:os.cmd` does not return error code, I would like to use `System.cmd` for better error handling.

`connected_deivces = System.cmd("usb-devices", ["|", "grep", "-A", "1", "Product="])`

So I tried to change function like above, but it does not execute command after pipeline.

How can I execute command with pipeline with `System.cmd`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`System.cmd` can only invoke one program directly. `os:cmd` passes the command to the default shell of the operating system which allows you to use pipes. To do the same thing with `System.cmd`, you can call `/bin/sh` if you're on a Unix:

```
System.cmd("/bin/sh", ["-c", "usb-devices | grep -A 1 Product="])
```

Comment: Check https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/main/System.html#shell/2